# FNT font file in C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, fonts, gdi+

I would like to know if I can use FNT font file in c# .net.

FNTs are not windows font file.

If such fonts are available, can you please tell me how to load it and change windows form font to FNT?

I use .Net GDI+ technology, but please let me know if WPF is better for this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are device fonts, a relic from the Windows 3.0 days before TrueType became available.  They contain bitmaps of (typically) 256 glyphs in a certain character set at fixed pre-selected point sizes.  They are not scalable beyond those fixed sizes.

Nope, neither GDI+ nor WPF supports them.  You'd have to fall back to raw GDI to still use them.  The file format isn't complicated, it would be technically possible to lift the bitmaps out of the file.  I'm not aware of existing code, although I'm sure somebody did.  Some kind of legacy font editor for example.

Comment: There's somebody else asking about .fon files today.  Coincidence?

Answer (score 0):

.NET uses either GDI+ (in WinForms) or WPF for its text handling and rendering.

So depending on what .NET technology you are using will determine what is supported.